# BizTalk "Receive Location" status remains disabled despite "Enable" attribute equal true in binding file

Tags: import, binding, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, receive-location

I imported the sample binding file from "BizTalk Server Administration Console" -> "Import -> Bindings...".

It created receive location successfully but despite in the file `<Enable>true</Enable>`, it created locations with status as disabled.

Is it possible to make it enable with the binding file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BindingInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Assembly="Microsoft.BizTalk.Deployment, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Version="3.5.1.0" BindingStatus="PartiallyBound" BoundEndpoints="43" TotalEndpoints="47">
  <Timestamp>2017-09-11T11:27:28.7543844+03:00</Timestamp>
  <DistributionListCollection />
  <ReceivePortCollection>
    <ReceivePort Name="XXXXXXXXXXX" IsTwoWay="true" BindingOption="1">
      <Description xsi:nil="true" />
      <ReceiveLocations>
        <ReceiveLocation Name="XXXXXXXXX_ReceiveLocation">
          <Description xsi:nil="true" />
          <Address>net.pipe://localhost/XXXXXXXXXX</Address>
          <PublicAddress />
          <Primary>false</Primary>
          <ReceiveLocationServiceWindowEnabled>false</ReceiveLocationServiceWindowEnabled>
          <ReceiveLocationFromTime>2000-01-01T21:00:00</ReceiveLocationFromTime>
          <ReceiveLocationToTime>2000-01-01T20:59:59</ReceiveLocationToTime>
          <ReceiveLocationStartDateEnabled>false</ReceiveLocationStartDateEnabled>
          <ReceiveLocationStartDate>2009-05-05T00:00:00</ReceiveLocationStartDate>
          <ReceiveLocationEndDateEnabled>false</ReceiveLocationEndDateEnabled>
          <ReceiveLocationEndDate>2009-05-06T23:59:59</ReceiveLocationEndDate>
          <ReceiveLocationTransportType Name="WCF-NetNamedPipe" Capabilities="907" ConfigurationClsid="148d2e28-d634-4127-aa9e-7d6298156bf1" />
          <ReceiveLocationTransportTypeData>&lt;CustomProps&gt;&lt;UseSSO vt="11"&gt;0&lt;/UseSSO&gt;&lt;InboundBodyLocation vt="8"&gt;UseBodyPath&lt;/InboundBodyLocation&gt;&lt;InboundBodyPathExpression vt="8"&gt;/*[local-name()='part']&lt;/InboundBodyPathExpression&gt;&lt;SendTimeout vt="8"&gt;00:30:00&lt;/SendTimeout&gt;&lt;OutboundXmlTemplate vt="8"&gt;&amp;lt;bts-msg-body xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/bts2007" encoding="xml"/&amp;gt;&lt;/OutboundXmlTemplate&gt;&lt;OpenTimeout vt="8"&gt;00:30:00&lt;/OpenTimeout&gt;&lt;SecurityMode vt="8"&gt;Transport&lt;/SecurityMode&gt;&lt;TransactionProtocol vt="8"&gt;OleTransactions&lt;/TransactionProtocol&gt;&lt;MaxReceivedMessageSize vt="3"&gt;2147483647&lt;/MaxReceivedMessageSize&gt;&lt;TransportProtectionLevel vt="8"&gt;EncryptAndSign&lt;/TransportProtectionLevel&gt;&lt;CloseTimeout vt="8"&gt;00:30:00&lt;/CloseTimeout&gt;&lt;SuspendMessageOnFailure vt="11"&gt;-1&lt;/SuspendMessageOnFailure&gt;&lt;EnableTransaction vt="11"&gt;0&lt;/EnableTransaction&gt;&lt;InboundNodeEncoding vt="8"&gt;Base64&lt;/InboundNodeEncoding&gt;&lt;IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults vt="11"&gt;-1&lt;/IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults&gt;&lt;MaxConcurrentCalls vt="3"&gt;300&lt;/MaxConcurrentCalls&gt;&lt;OutboundBodyLocation vt="8"&gt;UseBodyElement&lt;/OutboundBodyLocation&gt;&lt;/CustomProps&gt;</ReceiveLocationTransportTypeData>
          <ReceivePipeline Name="Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive" FullyQualifiedName="Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Type="1" TrackingOption="ServiceStartEnd MessageSendReceive PipelineEvents" Description="" />
          <ReceivePipelineData xsi:nil="true" />
          <SendPipeline Name="Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.PassThruTransmit" FullyQualifiedName="Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.PassThruTransmit, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Type="2" TrackingOption="ServiceStartEnd MessageSendReceive PipelineEvents" Description="" />
          <SendPipelineData xsi:nil="true" />
          <Enable>true</Enable>
          <ReceiveHandler Name="BizTalkServerApplication" HostTrusted="true">
            <TransportType Name="WCF-NetNamedPipe" Capabilities="907" ConfigurationClsid="148d2e28-d634-4127-aa9e-7d6298156bf1" />
          </ReceiveHandler>
        </ReceiveLocation>
      </ReceiveLocations>
      <SendPipelineData xsi:nil="true" />
      <Authentication>0</Authentication>
      <Tracking>255</Tracking>

      <OutboundTransforms />
      <RouteFailedMessage>false</RouteFailedMessage>
      <ApplicationName>XXXXXXXXXXX</ApplicationName>
    </ReceivePort>
    </ReceivePortCollection>
  <PartyCollection />
</BindingInfo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO is not possible, you have to import the bindings and then enable the Receive Locations through the Admin Console or PowerShell or WMI, ...